# how can limit the chracters in FloatField in django forms

Tags: python, django

I have this

```
area    = forms.FloatField(required=False)
```

I want that people should should not be able to add more than 20 characters or numbers like i have in `max_length` for char field

I dont want people trying pasting whole text file of number in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DecimalField` instead of `FloatField`.

```
area = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=20)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield).

Comment: keep in mind that `decimal.Decimal` is not the same as `float`. You should convert values to float if neccessary.